# Android 5.0 ListActivity not populating ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-5.0-lollipop, listactivity

I have a problem with my app that consists of a MainActivity which is a ListActivity. App worked just fine before, but now with Android 5.0 Lollipop, it doesn't show any content on the ListView. It doesn't crash, the view is just empty. Debugging tells me that my adapter has the data I want to show.

Layout for MainActivity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_image" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<MyClass> class = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ArrayList<MyItem> classlist;
    private Context context;
    ListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        classlist = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
        context = this;

        if (contentInMemory) {
            readFromMemory();
        } 
        if (!contentInMemory) {
            readFromOnline()
        }
    }

    private void readFromOnline() {
        //read content from online
        readOnline();
        doAfterLoad();
    }

    private void readFromMemory() {
        //read content from memory
        doAfterLoad();
    }

    private void doAfterLoad() {
        adapter = new ListAdapter(context, class);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void saveToMemory() {
        //saves to memory
    }

    private class readOnline extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //shows dialog
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            //reads content
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
            saveToMemory();
            doAfterLoad();
        }
    }

    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass>{
        private final Context context;

        public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyClass> class) {
            super(context, R.layout.myclass_listlayout, class);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myclass_listlayout, parent, false);
            //fills textviews with content
            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never set the adapter on your ListView. You also should just use Activity since you are using your own layout.

Comment: @JaredRummler I set the adapter in `doAfterLoad()`. Anyways I changed my ListActivity to Activity and tried that but no, it's not  working. I'm pretty sure it would have worked (as my code worked) with Android < 5.0, but for some reason Lollipop has changed something.

Comment: Post the new code. Your `setListAdapter` won't work because you are using your own layout. You need to find your ListView using `findViewById` and then set the adapter using `yourListView.setAdapter(adapter)`

Answer (score 0):

How should he inflate something?

You didn't override the

```
getCount()
```

Method in your

```
class Listadapter extends ArrayAdapter
```

which tells the adapter how much views he need 2 inflate. Without providing that information the adapter won't inflate! Return you array length or your list size in getCount

**Some additional Hints**

The Problem you explained is a common Problem caused by not returning a number >0 in getCount.

You can simply check this by adding a

```
Log.e("getView","invoked");
```

into your `getView(..)` method.

If it is not called most time the developers don't provide a valid return of getCount().

Comment: Adding that check to `getView()` method shows that it gets invoked without overriding `getCount()` as many times as it should. Adding the method doesn't change the behaviour.